# Firestore: Assign auto generated id to newly created document

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The purpose of createQuestionForTest() is to create a document in my firebase db inside a collection called *questions*. The way my method is now the newly created document has to be assigned a string id "ALo". **How do assign it an auto generated one instead?**

The code (typescript):

```
  createQuestionForTest(questionTxt: string, answers: string[]){
    this.db.collection(CollectionConstants.QUESTIONS).doc("ALo").set({
      questionTxt: questionTxt,
      answerIds: answers
    });
  }
```

The database:
[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image[![enter image description here])
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call the [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) method of the [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference), as follows:

```
  createQuestionForTest(questionTxt: string, answers: string[]){
    this.db.collection(CollectionConstants.QUESTIONS).add({
      questionTxt: questionTxt,
      answerIds: answers
    });
  }
```

As explained in the doc, it will "add a new document to this collection with the specified data, **assigning it a document ID automatically**".

Comment: let me give your +1 here

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm quite new in this field and must've missed that.